# Extract coordinates from SVG String

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, sorting

```
  let path_string='<path transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width=".074" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 274.75 301.4 L 275.41 303.36 L 275.41 307.28 L 289.11 293.57 "/>'
```

Above shows an SVG path code as a string, I want to extract the x and y coordinates of the path and store it in array. **The pattern is that all the coordinate numbers are seperated by spaces before and after.**

For example, the above code when used as input should output

```
x_coor_arr=[274.75,275.41,275.41,289.11];

y_coor_arr=[301.4,303.36,307.28,293.57];
```

How do I solve this efficiently?

Comment: Please explain why you need to process the complete `<path>` element's markup instead of just using the `d` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the d attribute from the path element and then:

```js
var svgRaw = 'M 274.75 301.4 L 275.41 303.36 L 275.41 307.28 L 289.11 293.57 ';
  svgRaw = svgRaw.split(' ');

  var coorX = [];
  var coorY = [];

  svgRaw = svgRaw.filter((item) => !['M', 'L', ''].includes(item));
  svgRaw.forEach((item, index = 1) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return coorX.push(item);
    }

    return coorY.push(item)
  });

  console.log(coorX, coorY);
```

Comment: Hi, your code does not work for svg as string. Here's a demo https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/ZEjqNJV?editors=0012

Comment: How do I solve this if svg as string :) ?

Comment: Why not get just `d` attr? The codepen you provided is getting the proper value, as you want